# How to import from an encrypted file?

Tags: python, import, obfuscation, pyarmor

I'm trying to get a little bit familiar with code obfuscating and package building. For this I made a simple file named "addCode.py" with a function that adds two numbers called "add". I published it to PyPI and to use it I just need to install the package and import the function:

```
from addCode import add
```

The next step I would like to make is to obfuscate the code in addCode.py using pyarmor so that someone who imports the package can use it but can't read the source code. I know this does not fully protect the code but I just want it to be good enough to hide it for the regular person. So I got the encrypted code and uploaded it to PyPI but the problem is that now I cannot import the "add" function because it is not possible to find the function in the file (eventhough the function is there, but encrypted).

To resume: is there anyway I can import a function from an encrypted with pyarmor? If not, is there any other encrypting tool that lets me both import functions and run the code without any errors?

Comment: why do you want to encrypt your PUBLIC library?

Comment: Like I said I would like to learn how to let other people use my functions but I don't want them to be reading my code. The code does not have some super secret capable of destroying governments, I just want to learn how to publish encrypted code, if that makes any sense :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly. But you may be able to encrypt your files, and then have one non-encrypted which would do the decryption in order to use them. But that also means that someone else could just replicate the steps to decrypt them too.

However I don't think you should focus on this at all. Either don't publish, or make it public.

Comment: Yes, having a file to decrypt kind of ruins the point of it. Thanks for the help, I researched a bit before posting here and found nothing, I guess this hasn't been really thought about by other people